# Why can I not use winget after installing Microsoft Desktop App Installer?

Tags: winget

I installed Microsoft Desktop App Installer

When I type `Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers` into Powershell i can see I have:
`Version: @{Version=1.19.10173.0}`

However, when I type `winget` into Powershell I get `“the term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.”`

I believe winget is in version 1.19.

I've rebooted and no difference.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my laptop, and the solution that worked for me was to install winget through Scoop.

```
scoop install winget
```

Is Scoop installed on your computer?